# Linq To Sql duplicate a row in update case

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates, datarow

I have a single entity that always duplicate a row when it needs to update:

```
    protected static Task RegisterToDisc(Task task)
    {         
        try
        {
            using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
            {
                //this will print an actual existing id from the db
                _log.Debug(task.ID);

                context.Tasks.InsertOnSubmit(task);
                context.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           //...
        }
        return task;
    }
```

When I print the id before the save, it is actually prints out an id that is really exists in the db.

this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskSet](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Result] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Priority] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeAsked] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimePerfomed] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SessionID] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TaskSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Edit**

The `task` is comming from the database already, task.ID  contains a `number` that is exists in the database, how come Linq inserts an entity with PK that is not null and in the db already.

in java hibernate you neet to `context.insertOrUpdate(task);` and it will decide what to do by the primary key.

Comment: where is your "Task" coming from before you get to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InsertOnSubmit` always marks the object for insertion. if you want to update the object u need to read it from database like

```
var objToUpdate = context.Tasks.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == Id);
objToUpdate.Property1 = "updated value";
objToUpdate.Property2 = "updated value";
//do it for all properties that need updating
context.SubmitChanges();//since the object is tracked by context it will automatically generate sql to reflect update in db
```

Comment: if Task is coming from db then just call `context.SubmitChanges` but here it would not do u any good because you are instantiating a new data context when trying to update object. the flow is: get object from context, make changes to it and then call `SubmitChanges` on **same context** that was used to fetch object from db

Comment: Thanks, I sent the context as a parameter.